# Starting multiple nodes do not allocate replica shards

Tags: elasticsearch, sharding

So, I had just started out with Elasticsearch on my local machine.

I have started 5 instances of Elasticsearch nodes. (simple `./bin/elasticsearch`)

`curl -s 'localhost:9200/_cat/nodes?v'` gives:

```
host      ip        heap.percent ram.percent load node.role master name
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1            5          99 3.13 d         m      Shirow Ishihara
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1            7         100 3.13 d         m      Madame Web
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1            5         100 3.13 d         m      Anthropomorpho
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1            5         100 3.13 d         m      Paste-Pot Pete
127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1            2         100 3.13 d         *      Mephisto
```

My index has 2 primary shards and 5 replicas (total 10 replicas).

I had read that ES automatically scales horizontally and assigns/moves shards to new nodes. However, still all the 10 replicas are unassigned and both the 2 primary shards are in the same node.

`curl -s 'localhost:9200/_cat/allocation?v'` gives:

```
shards disk.indices disk.used disk.avail disk.total disk.percent host      ip        node
     0           0b   105.5gb      6.2gb    111.8gb           94 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 Shirow Ishihara
     0           0b   105.5gb      6.2gb    111.8gb           94 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 Paste-Pot Pete
     2         318b   105.5gb      6.2gb    111.8gb           94 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 Mephisto
     0           0b   105.5gb      6.2gb    111.8gb           94 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 Anthropomorpho
     0           0b   105.5gb      6.2gb    111.8gb           94 127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 Madame Web
    10                                                                               UNASSIGNED
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information to diagnose the issue. There are others answers on stackoverflow that detail how to figure out why shards are unassigned (one of my top answers for example)

Comment: @Alcanzar: I've read your answer. I needed to know what I was doing wrong in this case. Hence, I have given all the information. Would be happy to provide more information.

Comment: What have you tried?  What's the output when you try to force a shard to allocate? What do the settings look like on your mappings?  How many replicas and shard.

Comment: Haven't tried forcing the shards to allocate as I wanted to know firstly what was the issue of them not being automatically allocated. Already stated the number of shards and replicas along with disk stats.

Comment: Trying to force it to allocate will tell you why it isn't doing it automatically

Answer (score 0):

You have too few available disk space an ES is actually trying to move away some shards. But all your nodes are on the same machine so there is nowhere else where to move them and they stay unassigned. The used disk space is more than 90% of the total disk size and ES is hitting the the high watermark.

Read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/disk-allocator.html) more about this.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful. I'll try it out it again after freeing disk space and post it here.

Comment: I can't upvote this answer due to low reputation. But will surely do to help other developers as well.